# How to read a directory in webapp folder of Maven web application

Tags: java, file, file-io, directory

I'm working in maven web application. I need to read a directory(For ex: Files) in my webapp folder as follows,

```
Java.io.File file = new Java.io.File("path");
```

But I don't know how to specify the path of the directory here.

Comment: how is this question related to Maven?

Comment: I'm working ina maven web application. So people who are working in Maven will know the hierarchy of folders in maven application.

Comment: your assumption that the web-app directory structure (deployed on server) is the same as your maven directory structure is wrong

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't give local path addresses. Path should be a relative address, e.g. `/files/images` under your web archive (.war) folder.

To use relative paths properly, I suggest you to add your target folder to the resources definiton of POM.xml, check out these pages 
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-change-maven-resources-folder-location/
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

You can refer to resources folder easily with something like this:

```
this.class.getResource("Mydirectory/SubDirectory");
```

Comment: I tried as you said. But its not working. Java.io.File file = new Java.io.File("/files/subdirectory");

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of your web-app directory hierarchy?

Comment: My web-app directory hierarchy is Myapplication/src/main/webapp/Mydirectory/SubDirectory

Comment: @Gnik your web-app directory structure can be different from your sources structure

Comment: You can define a folder under your web-app directory as a resource in POM.xml then you can use it with getResource() call.

Comment: By which object i can access the getResource() call. Guys Please help me. Give me a sample.

Comment: You don't need an object. Suppose you have a class called Main.  Main.class.getResource() is the call you need.

Comment: How can i give url for new File("path") using getResource(). help me. Give me sample

Comment: Google it. You may not need to create a File object. getResource() method takes path string as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt how relatives paths work, it's always best to do something like that:

```
System.out.println(new File("/my/desired/directory").getAbsolutePath());
```

This will print out the path in which classpath will look for the files.

Assuming:

- servlet container webapps dir is located in: `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps`
- your webapp is called `my-webapp.war`

You should see the following output: `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/my-webapp/my/desired/directory`

Another pointer: you have mentioned that you are looking for `webapp` directory. I hope you know that this directory will not end up in `*.war` - **it's contents will**.

Comment: I'm using Glassfish as web server

Answer (score 0):

War files are not always expanded when they are deployed to an app server, so it's possible that a relative path won't exist in a filesystem *at all*.

Best bets are to use getResource from the class loader, which will return things in the class path (the WEB-INF/lib directory, etc), or to use the [getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) method of ServletContext to find things in the web application itself.